# How do I take data from a 2D array, find repeating elements in first index and group relating elements from another index in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a two dimensional array in PHP, the first index is the name of the item in the index and the other indexes is other information of the item.  There are duplicate names in the first index but not in the second.

What I want to do is add the array to a table, but only have each name show up once and have all the unique data from the second index show up in a drop down list (select tag).

So I have:

```
$array[0][0] = foo
$array[0][1] = foo
$array[0][2] = foo

$array[0][3] = bar
$array[0][4] = bar
```

and

```
$array[1][0] = 1
$array[1][1] = 2
$array[1][2] = 3

$array[1][3] = 4
$array[1][4] = 5
```

What I want is a table with

```
foo | (select from 1-3)
bar | (select from 4-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);

$array[0][0] = 'foo';
$array[0][1] = 'foo';
$array[0][2] = 'foo';

$array[0][3] = 'bar';
$array[0][4] = 'bar';

$array[1][0] = 1;
$array[1][1] = 2;
$array[1][2] = 3;

$array[1][3] = 4;
$array[1][4] = 5;

// get new array without duplicate values
$uniqueValueArray = array_unique($array[0]);

$result = [];

foreach ($uniqueValueArray as $value)
{
    $row = ['value' => $value, 'ids' => []];

    // get keys form value array for given value
    $valueKeys = array_keys($array[0], $value);

    // find id form ids array for this value
    foreach ($valueKeys as $key)
    {
        $row['ids'][] = $array[1][$key];
    }

    $result[] = $row;
}

var_dump($result);
```